# Google Pay decryption error: Could not verify intermediate signing key signature

Tags: encryption, google-pay, tink

I am trying to decrypt a google payment token using Python google-pay-token-decryption package following this link https://github.com/yoyowallet/google-pay-token-decryption. Currently I keep getting errors such as **Could not verify message signature** and **Could not verify intermediate signing key signature**. I tried changing all "\u003d" and "\u003d" in my token to "=" and still getting the same results. However, if I ignore the verification it will successfully decrypt. Does anyone know what these errors mean?

```
signingKey = [{"keyValue":"MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEIsFro6K+IUxRr4yFTOTO+kFCCEvHo7B9IOMLxah6c977oFzX\/beObH4a9OfosMHmft3JJZ6B3xpjIb8kduK4\/A==","protocolVersion":"ECv1"},{"keyValue":"MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEGnJ7Yo1sX9b4kr4Aa5uq58JRQfzD8bIJXw7WXaap\/hVE+PnFxvjx4nVxt79SdRuUVeu++HZD0cGAv4IOznc96w==","protocolVersion":"ECv2","keyExpiration":"2154841200000"},{"keyValue":"MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEGnJ7Yo1sX9b4kr4Aa5uq58JRQfzD8bIJXw7WXaap\/hVE+PnFxvjx4nVxt79SdRuUVeu++HZD0cGAv4IOznc96w==","protocolVersion":"ECv2SigningOnly","keyExpiration":"2154841200000"}]
recipient_id = "merchant:12345678901234567890"
private_key = "string"

decryptor = GooglePayTokenDecryptor(signingKey, recipient_id, private_key)
decrypted_token = decryptor.decrypt_token(token, False)
```

I've also tried the Tink library in Java and also getting Exceptions related to verifying signature.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.GeneralSecurityException: cannot verify signature
    at com.google.crypto.tink.apps.paymentmethodtoken.PaymentMethodTokenRecipient.verify(PaymentMethodTokenRecipient.java:461)
    at com.google.crypto.tink.apps.paymentmethodtoken.PaymentMethodTokenRecipient.verifyECV2(PaymentMethodTokenRecipient.java:399)
    at com.google.crypto.tink.apps.paymentmethodtoken.PaymentMethodTokenRecipient.unsealECV2(PaymentMethodTokenRecipient.java:365)
    at com.google.crypto.tink.apps.paymentmethodtoken.PaymentMethodTokenRecipient.unseal(PaymentMethodTokenRecipient.java:342)
    at org.example.AeadExample.main(AeadExample.java:33)
```

Comment: You shouldn't change the "\u003d" to "=" in the serialized intermediate signing key. Can you edit your question to show the token you are trying to pass to decryptor.decrypt_token? You should also make sure that the intermediate signing key is not expired (you should check its expiration timestamp). If it's not expired, perhaps the root signing keys you are using are incorrect (the signingKey variable). There are different keys for test environment and production environment.

Comment: Also "Could not verify message signature" and "Could not verify intermediate signing key signature" are different errors. There are two signatures that need to be verified. Each of these errors indicates a failure to verify a different signature.